# Change Iris color picker Value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

I'm using Iris color picker http://automattic.github.io/Iris/

And I need when the user click on button the color picker change to red automatically

The problem I'm facing is the input Value Changed but the color picker still on the old color

Here is my code in action jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/38ZAX/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#color-picker').iris({
        hide: false,
        palettes: true
    });
});

$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $('#color-picker').val('#f33939');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
$('#color-picker').iris('color', '#f33939');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/38ZAX/1/)